# Bean name resolution in Spring using @Bean and @Qualifier annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I just found a behaviour of Spring that I cannot understand. I am using Spring Boot 1.5.x.

In a configuration class, I declared two different beans.

```
@Configuration
class Config {
    @Bean("regularRestTemplate")
    public RestTemplate regularRestTemplate(String toLog) {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder().setConnectTimeout(100)
                                        .setReadTimeout(100)
                                        .additionalInterceptors((request, body, execution) -> {
                                            log.info("Inside the interceptor {}", toLog);
                                            return execution.execute(request, body);
                                        })
                                        .build();
    }
    @Bean("exceptionalRestTemplate")
    public RestTemplate regularRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder().setConnectTimeout(100)
                                        .setReadTimeout(100)
                                        .build()
    }
}
```

Then, I have a class that should use the bean called `exceptionalRestTemplate`.

```
@Component
class Client {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Autowired
    public Client(@Qualifier("exceptionalRestTemplate") RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }
    // Code that uses the injected rest template
}
```

Since I specified the name of the bean I want to be injected using the `@Qualifier` annotation, I would expect that Spring injects the bean called `exceptionalRestTemplate`. However, the bean called `regularRestTemplate` is actually used during the injection process.

It turns out that the problem was in the name of the methods that declare the beans in the configuration class. Both are colled `regularRestTemplate`. Changing the second method name, solve the problem.

My question is, why? I know that Spring uses the names of classes and methods annotated with the `@Bean` or with the `@Component`, `@Service`, etc... annotations to give a name to Java object inside the resolution map. But, I supposed that giving a name inside these annotations would override this behaviour.

Does anybody tell me what's going on?

Comment: The methods function as factory methods and in the `ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader` this is handled specially. Doing this in 2 seperate `@Configuration` annotated classes would work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bean qualifier and bean name are different meanings. You qualified new bean but tried to override it (arguments don't matter). In your application, you cannot override beans so you have the only first one.

You can check this 'theory'. Add a parameter in your configuration

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

and start your application again. After that, you will have only a second bean.

This is an explanation of the collision. But the solution is a separation of beans to different configurations.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Have you any reference to the official documentation?

Comment: Nope. Just experience and observations.

Comment: This answer is actually wrong as the problem has nothing to do with `@Qualifier` vs `bean name`. The problem here with equally-named bean factory methods in the same `@Configuration` class, as @m-denium noted. The context will actually have TWO beans, each with own name and qualifier, but both will be created using the same factory method (one of two `regularRestTemplate(..)` methods), as one of them is lost during `ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader` work. So, the qualifier works fine. It's the bean creation that works wrong. Seems like a bug to me (or you can name it "specialty", hehe).

Comment: According to the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) _the bean name is considered a default qualifier value._ There is no qualifiers has been specified in bean definition so in this particular case qualifier and name are one and the same.